# How to fix the error in initializing array of E elements in constructor?

Tags: java, tree, heap

I am working with data structures and i cannot seem to initialize array of generic elements;

```
public class Heap <'E extends Comparable<E>'> { 

private E elements[];

public Heap(int n) {

    E[] es = (E[]) new Object[n];
    elements=es;

    }
}

public static void main(String[]args) {

        Heap<Integer>tree=new Heap<Integer>(10);
}
```

When i run the program i get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
>       at heaptree.Heap.(Heap.java:16)
>       at heaptree.Heap.main(Heap.java:70)

Can somebody suggest a way to fix this?

Comment: Well ... An `Object[]` is not a `Comparable[]`. You cannot cast it like that. Maybe you wanted to do `E[] es = (E[]) new Comparable[n]`?

Comment: Actually i need an array of generic elements and they have to have a logic to compare themselvs to one another

Comment: It's impossible to create a generic array. Try to use a generic collection instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

You can't do it that way in Java, no chance. Because you'd need information at run-time that's only availyble at compile-time. You simply can't create an array of a generic type.

Wherever you create a `new Heap<Whatever>`, only the compiler knows that you want a `Whatever` for your generic `E` type. Inside the E constructor you try to create an array that can be used as `E[]`, meaning a `Whatever[]` in that example case. In Java, `Whatever[]` is not a subclass of e.g. `Object[]`, although `Whatever` is of course a subclass of `Object`. You can't use a `Whatever[]` where an `Object[]` is expected, nor the other way round.

So, only an exact `Whatever[]` array can be used where a `Whatever[]` array is expected, leaving you in need to know at runtime that this time you have to create an array of `Whatever`s. And the `<Whatever>` information is erased by the compiler, not available at runtime.

### Workaround / Solution

If you look at the sources of e.g. `ArrayList`, you'll see that the experts hav done it differently, not trying to create an array of the specific type, but of a constant, general type `Object`. ArrayList only casts things like the return value of the `get()` method to the generic type, not the internal array itself.

So, create your array with a fixed type that covers all possible `E` types, e.g. `Comparable[]`, and have methods like `get()` cast the array element to `E` before returning it.

Or, you can pass the `E` class object into the constructor like `Heap(Class<E> targetClass, int n)`, so you get it available at run-time, and use `Array.newInstance(targetClass, n)` with that class object and the desired dimension.